# Correct use of repeated property?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, python-2.7

I need orders / purchases that allow many items for instance something like

```
class Purchase(db.Model):
  '''a completed transaction'''
  item = db.ReferenceProperty(Item, repeated=True))
```

Is the repeated keyword legal and used in the correct manner here? What are my other options? Should I do it with a repeated stringproperty instead?

`item_ids = model.StringProperty(repeated=True)`
or with repeated KeyProperties?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [ListProperty](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ListProperty):

```
class Purchase(db.Model):
    items = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
```

It is used like a python list:

```
p = Purchase()
p.items = [item1.key(), item2.key(), item3.key()]
```

In queries however it looks like a single-valued field. Every value of ListProperty is indexed separately.

Query below will return all purchases which contain the `item1`:

```
Purchase.all().filter('items =', item1.key())
```

Query below will return all purchases which contain either `item1` or `item2`:

```
Purchase.all().wilter('items IN', [item1.key(), item2.key()])
```

If you will ever need to index more than one ListProperty don't forget to familiarize your self with [exploding-indexes](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Big_Entities_and_Exploding_Indexes).

Comment: Hi Nick. :-)  The confusion seems to be between NDB and db.  In NDB you use repeated=True while in db you use ListProperty.

Comment: Thank you for the answers and the comment. Most natural for my model would be a repeated Keyproperty and I will try if it works since I like the way NDB works with keys and its clean syntax.

Comment: I wasn't even aware of `ndb`. I appreciate your comment very much!